# Can't access JSON object sent to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question. I have searched for an answer but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to send quite a large JSON object to a PHP file via POST.

This is my JavaScript code :

```
var grid = 
    {
        "user": 1,
        "grid": JSON.stringify(hz),
        "week": WEEK,
        "AP": AP,
        "X_VAL": X_VAL,
        "Y_VAL": Y_VAL
    };

    grid = JSON.stringify(grid);

$.ajax({
        url:"php/saveGrid.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : "g="+grid,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

This is my PHP code :

```
$g = stripslashes($_REQUEST["g"]);
echo $AP = $g->AP;
```

But this returns an error which says :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use dataType: "json",

Comment: Try looking at the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST["g"])`. What does it look like? Is it a string, a PHP array or a JSON-encoded array?

Comment: try something like this  $g['AP'];

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya — Why? We can't see what the output from the PHP is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are trying to treat a string of JSON as if it were a PHP object.

You need to parse it first.

```
$g = stripslashes($_REQUEST["g"]);
$g = json_decode($g);
echo $AP = $g->AP;
```

You also have some secondary issues.

---

You failed to URL encode the JSON, so if it contains characters with special meaning in URLS, it will break.

> ```
> data : "g="+grid,
> ```

should be:

```
data : { g: grid },
```

---

You should not need to run stripslashes over input from $_REQUEST/POST/GET.

If you don't have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, then it could break the incoming data if it contains slashes.

If you do have magic quotes turned on, then you should turn them off or upgrade to a modern version of PHP (which wouldn't support them).

---

Nesting JSON inside JSON is silly. It bloats the data and makes it more work to read.

> ```
> "grid": JSON.stringify(hz),
> ```

should be:

```
 grid: hz,
```

---

`$_REQUEST` could get data from the query string, or the request body, or a cookie. You know it is coming in the request body so just use `$_POST` to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Actually, if I add the stripslashes function, it gives me the same error. If I remove it and just decode, then it works.

Comment: @ALR — I did say that it had the potential to break your data. Clearly it has.

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice and removed the nested JSON and URL encoded the JSON. The stripslashes still causes it to break though, so I just left it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the json object then can use it as an array. Try, `json_decode`. Like,

```
$g = stripslashes($_REQUEST["g"]);
$json_de=json_decode($g);
echo $AP = $json_de['AP'];
```

Or if you want to see the full array then use,

```
print_r($json_de);
```

Hope this will help you.